# How can I generate a MSI package name according to its version?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer, version, setup-project

In a Visual Studio setup project, is there a way to generate automaticaly the MSI fileName according to the current application version number?

Comment: In the post build event, I use a batch command file to extract the "ProductVersion" from the project file (.vdproj) and append it to the generated MSI file. That was the easiest way for me to do what you want to do.

Comment: this is only works first time after again re-install not working. for example setup_V1.0 installed and using Postbuild event generate other msi with different version like setup_V2.0 and when you reinstall this, Error comes. any help ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you able to fire post-build code when your .MSI is built? If so, you can use File.IO to rename the file and use something like:

```
System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion
```